# Linux mint suddenly stopped detecting wireless card

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, drivers

When I first installed Linux Mint, my wifi worked without me having to do anything. One day ago, Linux stopped giving me the option to connect to a wifi network half a minute after booting; now that happens immediately. Does anyone know what could be happening? I am running Linux Mint 18.1 on an Acer Asprite VN7-591g. My wireless card is a Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA34AC. The result of running sudo lshw -C network can be found at https://pastebin.com/6a2WAEpC. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
The result of running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` :

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac 
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network
Adapter [11ad:0804]
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.   
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L , Please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` , becuase the pastbin doesn't contain the required information about your wifi card

Comment: Unlod the `wl` module then load the `ath10k_pci`  : `sudo rmmod wl ath10k_pci` then `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci`

Comment: My computer can't find neither the wl module nor the ath10k_pci module.